# Can I use TestFlight with Ionic 3 without one MacOS?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, testflight, ionic-native, ionic-view

So I'm developing one application with Ionic 3 and we had some problems to test push notifications and generate one test version for iOS users.

Recently Ionic View was removed from Apple store, and same with the Ionic View in the apple store we had some problems to test push notifications, I know that Apple has TestFlight and we think that we can use TestFlight for our iOS users but I don't have one mac but I have Ionic Pro.

My doubt is that "Can I use Ionic Pro to generate one version to use in TestFlight without one MacOS?"

Comment: Sorry posted a reply and realized that my data point might be old/irrelevant;/ I am very confident that you can avoid macOS but it might be much more painful to do that than actually getting a mac.

Comment: Actually, I want to buy one MacOS but unfortunately, I can't do it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ionic Pro to do most of what you're looking for, EXCEPT creating the proper .p12 certificate file.  As far as I know, you must use a Mac for that.  Fortunately, that's a one-time process, so you can perform other aspects of the build process within Ionic Pro.

So, basically you need to create your .p12 certification file on a mac, and
upload it to Ionic Pro -> Settings -> Certificates. You can then build .ipa files with proper credentials in the cloud. Then... you have to upload the ipa file to the app store, and distribute it via TestFlight there.

Another option: There is a pay-as-you-go Mac cloud account service (https://www.macincloud.com/) that might be perfect for what you're doing, specifically since you either only need to create the certificates (at best)  or you'd only have to use it when you were creating builds and uploading them via XCode Application Loader. (at worst)  Perhaps that's something that you might want to explore?  I will say, it is much easier doing that kind of development directly from within a Mac environment, unfortunately.